# Error retrieving parent for item in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

New to Android Development. I have created a "Hello World" project in Android Studio (Version 1.3.1). I am experimenting how to show logs and see how does the app run. Here is what I have in my MainActivity.java which was automatically created by Android Studio and I only added the Log tag.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MjMessageFromActivities"
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I run the app to see the logs in DDMS, I receive below three error:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And here is the build.gradle content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Could you please guide me on how to fix above error in order to see the logs?

Comment: It is error caused by styles that come predefined when you download API level 22 or 23 make sure in your android sdk manager you have API level lolipop or Marshmallow present

Comment: did you try googling on "finished with non-zero exit value 1".

Comment: Yes I did google it but didn't find out what to change in order to fix the error.